Bluetooth not working : Unbranded CSR clone detected : Ubuntu 24.04
I have dual boot. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24.04. I have bluetooth dongle which works well on windows however same is not working on ubuntu. Here is the  error.
$sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth


[    8.066445] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.066483] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.066489] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.066492] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.066500] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.858884] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=9 rev=3120
[    8.858892] Bluetooth: hci0: LMP ver=9 subver=22bb; manufacturer=10
[    8.858895] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[   13.943727] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[   13.943780] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[   13.943784] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Read Default Erroneous Data Reporting command is advertised, but not supported.
[   13.943786] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[   15.925647] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.925655] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.925662] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.987589] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110

I know this problem is reported at many places however i couldnt find solution anywhere.
I dont know who will be able to help me.
Here are more details
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: bc:5f:f4:b8:18:14
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0010000-f0010fff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:dfb00000-dfb0ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@2:1.1
       logical name: wlx7cc2c627113b
       serial: 7c:c2:c6:27:11:3b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.110 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

$ hciconfig -a

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:14 acl:0 sco:0 events:1 errors:0
    TX bytes:3 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:1
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 


Please append to your question the output of the following command: 'sudo lshw -C network'

Appended the output of sudo lshw -C network

It is sort of unreadable though. Can you format it with {...} (Select text and hit the button.) Also could you append the output of the following command: 'hciconfig -a' formatted.

formatted and ran given command
